# How to run IIS Express development server,not ASP.NET development server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012

In project A, it runs as an IIS server.
When open A project, visual studio asks you which option to choose.but In project B, it runs as ASP.Net server. Is there a way to run B project as IIS server?

Comment: Go to your projects property page, you will have the option to use external server or the in-built server.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use below steps to use the IIS express instead of the local IIS server.

1.Right-click your Project within the Solution Explorer area.

2.Select Properties...

[image]

3.Select the Web tab on the left.

4.Check that the Local IIS Web Server radio button and use IIS express is checked.

[image]